# Visual Studio Report Dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, dataset

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string k { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> l { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<C> a { get; set; }
}


public class C
{
    public string m { get; set; }
}
```

With an array of `A` I have to build a report using `Visual Studio 2013`. The idea was to create a `DataSet` whitch matches this structure and then create subreports in the main report. Problem: I don't know how to create the Dataset; and maybe hard to write this report(s).

Another idea is to create a new class `flatting` my array as following:

```
class D {
    public string k { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string m { get; set; }

}
```

In this way the Dataset would be easy to create and maybe also the report itself.

Need your opinions and in case of first solution I'd need help to create the Dataset.